# Step definitions remain 'Undefined' while using Examples keyword despite being defined

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I've created the following scenario in my feature file:

```
Scenario Outline: User can navigate to expected url by selecting the associated link
        Given Application configured for testing
        And on the Test page screen
        When the user selects link for <pageName> - <dataTestId>
        Then the user navigates to the expected url: <urlPathName>
        Examples:
            | pageName | dataTestId | urlPathName |
            | Test Page | passwordTestLink  | passwordTest |
            | Custom Test | customTestLink  | customTest |
```

I have created corresponding test definitions for each step. But when I run the test the When and Then steps are returning as 'Undefined'. i.e. Cucumber can't find the steps. The error message is:

> ? When the user selects link for Custom Test - customTestLink
> Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:Here is an example of one of the steps which is not being found:
> When('the user selects link for Custom Test - customTestLink', async function () {
> // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
> return 'pending';
> });

```
When('the user selects link for {string} - {string}', async function( dataTestId:string) {
    administrationPage = new AdministrationPage(fixture.page);
    await administrationPage.clickLink(dataTestId);
})
```

I'm not sure why the test is not being found, but I assume it's to do with the two string parameters. What do I need to change to ensure the step definitions are found by Cucumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step

```
When the user selects link for <pageName> - <dataTestId>
```

Does not match your step definition.

```
When('the user selects link for {string} - {string}', async function( dataTestId:string) {
```

To match `{string}`, your step should use qoutes.

```
When the user selects link for "<pageName>" - "<dataTestId>"
```

And your step definition should have two arguments. One for each parameter in the cucumber expression.

```
When('the user selects link for {string} - {string}', async function(pageName:string, dataTestId:string) {
```